# Confusing shorthand operator (?) statement in C#

Tags: c++-cli

I am a C++/CLI programmer and have been trying to implement a very lightweight Json library for my program. I have a nice working code now but the problem is that its about 5 times slower than some of the JSON parsers out there for example Newtonsoft.JSON. So, I tried studying its code to see why it is so fast and came across this statement I cannot wrap my head around. I have researched a lot on google and around here but nothing seems to be able to help me **fully** understand. Consider the following statement.

```
JsonPosition? currentPosition = ((_currentState != State.ArrayStart && _currentState != State.ConstructorStart && _currentState != State.ObjectStart) ? new JsonPosition?(_currentPosition) : null);
```

Here, **JsonPosition** is a class that has some properties. It only has one constructor that takes **JsonContainerType** (an enum class) value as an argument. **_currentPosition** is of the type **JsonPosition**. **_currentState** is a variable that holds value of an enum class called **State**.

To me, it translates to the following.

```
JsonPosition^ currentPosition = ((_currentState != State::ArrayStart && _currentState != State::ConstructorStart && _currentState != State::ObjectStart) ? something : nullptr);
```

I cannot make sense of the **new JsonPosition?(_currentPosition)** part because of (a) the question mark placed between the class name and opening circular bracket, and (b) JsonPosition does not have a constructor that takes an argument of the type JsonPosition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this article](https://www.bytehide.com/blog/struct-constructor-csharp) that says:

> you cannot define a custom default constructor for structs in C#. The compiler automatically provides a default constructor that initializes all fields to their default values.

Taking that as my base, I further did more reliable research and figured out that apparently the C# compiler auto-generates a default constructor for value types (struct is a value type). Therefore allowing JsonPosition to be a nullable type. The code would translate as follows should the C++/CLI compiler would do the same, but since it does not, one must write a default constructor themself.

```
System::Nullable<JsonPosition^> currentPosition = ((_currentState != State::ArrayStart && _currentState != State::ConstructorStart && _currentState != State::ObjectStart) ? System::Nullable<JsonPosition^>(_currentPosition) : nullptr);
```

In C++/CLI, the code would be written as follows since in C++/CLI we use the reference handle (**^**) which unto itself can be null (nullptr) therefore eliminating the need for it to be wrapped in a System::Nullable wrapper.

**new JsonPosition?(_currentPosition)** would translate directly to just **_currentPosition**.

```
JsonPosition^ currentPosition = ((_currentState != State::ArrayStart && _currentState != State::ConstructorStart && _currentState != State::ObjectStart) ? _currentPosition : nullptr);
```

It is also explicitly stated in Microsoft documentation that in C# 8.0 and later, nullable value types (like JsonPosition?) can represent both a value and null. So, that's something to keep in mind as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be the answer.

```
JsonPosition^ currentPosition = ((_currentState != State::ArrayStart && _currentState != State::ConstructorStart && _currentState != State::ObjectStart) ? gcnew JsonPosition(_currentPosition) : nullptr);
```

`JsonPosition?` is a nullable type. It means that `currentPosition` can be assigned `null`. The conditional operator checks if `_currentState` is not equal to `State.ArrayStart`, `State.ConstructorStart`, and `State.ObjectStart`. If that condition is `true`, it executes the expression before (`new JsonPosition?(_currentPosition)`); otherwise, it executes the expression after (`null`).

Comment: Maybe try reading the question again. I'm clear on the short-hand boolean operation. The problem I am having is specifically on the "JsonPosition?(" part. What's the question mark here for? Also, JsonPosition does not have any constructor that takes JsonPosition object as an argument (as state in the question originally). So, how are they using _currentPosition (whose type is JsonPosition) to initialize an instance of JsonPosition? Hope that brings clarity.